# Oracle APEX filter change dynamically in saved reports

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, interactive

I have an IR with **saved reports** where filters has been added to the column Year = 2015. I need to write a plsql procedure to update the Year filter to Year = 2016.
How can i achieve such a scenario. I looked in to the API and it didn't give me any thing. the only option i can come up with is changing data manually in the DB.
below is the query i used to get the saved private reports.

```
SELECT  a.flow_id,a.page_id,a.status,a.application_user,a.name, b.interactive_report_id, c.condition_type,c.column_name,c.operator,c.expr
FROM apex_040000.wwv_flow_worksheet_rpts a, apex_application_page_ir b, apex_040000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_CONDITIONS c
WHERE a.flow_id = :APP_ID
AND a.page_id = b.page_id
AND b.application_id = a.flow_id
AND a.worksheet_id = b.interactive_report_id
AND a.status = 'PRIVATE'
AND c.report_id = a.id
AND c.column_name='YEAR'
and a.page_id= :APP_PAGE_ID
```

Would i be able to succeed wth this approach. Is there any other solution for this.
?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `apex_util.ir_clear(p_page_id => 200001)` to clear all filters and other settings (only sort and column visibility remains) or `apex_util.ir_reset(p_page_id => 200001)` to reset your current report to Primary report. And then `apex_util.ir_filter` to set new filter. This actions not literally modify your saved report, but changes it's current setting. At next time saved report will be same as before clear or reset.

Comment: what if we have multiple filters other than year. ? we want to change only the year filter. there are many IRs with different different filters, i need to change only the year of em

Comment: I recommended edit all saved report and remove Year filter. Then you can set year by calling apex_util.ir_filter or IR_column_name URL param.

Comment: the filters are added by the users for a particular year. we cannot remove them unless they are agreed upon. I want to have procedure which takes the required year as input and change all the IR year filter to that and the IR has a year filter added previously.